# Setting up a Lib Project and Unit Test Project in same workspace

Tags: codeblocks

I have a codeblocks workspace, with a static lib project in it. I wish to add another project with unit tests (gtest) for the lib, and have it link the static lib to test it. Is there an equivalent to Visual studio's adding a reference on the unit test project to the lib project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there isn't.

You can make your unit-test project *dependent* on your library project,
so that when you rebuild the unit-test project, C::B will check for changes
to the library project and if there are any, rebuild it first.

To do this:

- Navigate **Properties** -> **Project's dependencies** from your
  unit-test project
- In the project dependencies dialog, tick the checkbox for your library
  project; then OK out.

But you must still manually configure your unit-test project to link
your library.

- Navigate **Build options** -> **Linker** -> **Libraries** -> **Add** from your
  unit-test project.
- Use the **"..."** filesystem explorer option to navigate to the directory
  in which your library gets built; select the libary and OK out. You have a 
  choice between the Debug and  Release builds of your library (`path/to/your/
  library/bin/Debug/libYourLib.a` v. `path/to/your/library/bin/Release/libYourLib.a`).
  Presumably you your choice will reflect the Debug/Release configuration of your unit-test
  project.

Your static library will then be linked when you build the unit test project.